# Subdirectories in Websites

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I got something I need some help on :).
I have several sub-directories inside of my website (BlackVikingPro.com)
Such as
lab.blackvikingpro.com
Or irc.blackvikingpro.com

I want to make these directories only accessible through the url (lab.blackvikingpro.com) not be able to go (BlackVikingPro.com/lab).
Which is accessible either way. I just prefer for users to only go through (lab.blah.com) not (blah.com/lab)

Any way I can do this redirect method using htaccess? Maybe even JavaScript or php. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your **subdomains** are accessible under the main domain as well, you have code somewhere that does that with url-rewriting, otherwise the **subdomains** wouldn't be accessible that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a subdomain configuration. In your host just create a subdomain that points to your desired folder.

**Subdomain**: lab.blah.com

**Document-root**: /your/public_html/lab

This configuration is able in your host panel (Cpanel...) in domain area.

Comment: This just describes what OP already did.  He's looking to block requests to blah.com/lab which this does not do.

Comment: Yep, is true. I didn't understand correctly the question. In this case what is possible to do is validate the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and if is something like: blah.com/lab just redirect to lab.blah.com.

Comment: @AndreCardoso, so if I put in the PHP code "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" then make the if statement equal to whatever, then redirect it. This should work right?

Comment: @AndreCardoso, So I used this method. `<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "https://blackvikingpro.com/lab") {
        header('Location: https://lab.blackvikingpro.com/');
    } ?>`. How come this doesn't work?